# unable to filter the column if add two attributes in a template in kendo data grid

Tags: filter, datagrid, kendo-ui

```
in this below example (Please open jsfiddle link) i was unable to filter the first column with both first name and last name. I can only filter with first name  can anyone help on this please.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbb5Z/1927/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the filter working you have to either:

Make it a column in your datasource (for ex. FullName):http://jsfiddle.net/n6sso6s3/

Write a custom filter like:

```
filter: {
            logic: "or",
            filters: [{
                  field: "FirstName",
                  operator: "eq",
                  value: e.data.FirstName
            },
            {
              field: "LastName",
              operator: "eq",
              value: e.data.LastName
          }]
  }
```

Or add a fullName() function to your model like :http://jsbin.com/haxawupiye/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am very new to kendo. can you please provide working jsfiddle example

Comment: its working great. if I want to use the template, i mean i would like to put the first name in anchor tag. i have incorporated the change but it is taking like a string. can you please tell me how to use the template for this

Comment: Filters are applied to fields so as long as you have your field set to fullName you can add whatever you want as template: http://jsfiddle.net/L3g3zpfk/